# How to convert the order of a string in R?

Tags: r

Update: I used @rawr's suggestion. Thanks!

I'm taking a beginner class in R - and combined with an extremely unclear textbook (Learning R) and the fact that assignment questions are often vague, I have a lot of trouble figuring things out.

The question I have now is: Given a person’s full name in the format of firstName middleName lastName, write R code(s) to convert it to the format of lastName, middleInitial, firstName. In the case of Michael Carlos Dumas, the converted name is Dumas, C. Michael. (Hint: use str_split in stringr library to parse the full name)

What I have so far is:

```
name <- ("Michael Carlos Dumas")
nameSplit <- strsplit(name," ")
```

Output is:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Michael" "Carlos"  "Dumas"
```

But now that the name is split, I have no idea how to proceed or what function to use in order to rearrange the format of the name, as well as add the proper punctuation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See `?paste` for a starting point

Comment: also take a look at `nameSplit[[1]]`, `sort(nameSplit[[1]])`, and `nameSplit[[1]][1]`.

Comment: Not sure how `sort()` is useful here.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by this code:

```
> sapply(nameSplit,function(x){ return (paste0(x[3],', ',substr(x[2],1,1),'. ',x[1]))})
[1] "Dumas, C. Michael"
```